# page object gem table method throwing error

Tags: page-object-gem

When trying to get the value from a table cell using the page object gem I am getting the following error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: a is undefined
```

The code which errors is the following

```
table(:left_table, :xpath => "//*[@class ='table']")

left_table_element[1]['Publisher'].text
```

However curiously if I put

```
left_table_element[1][2].text
```

no errors are thrown.

When debugging I can see that the error is being thrown on the `table = parent` line in the `TableRow` module

```
def find_index_by_title(title)
          table = parent
          parent_tag_name = parent.element.tag_name
          table = table.parent if (parent_tag_name == 'tbody' || parent_tag_name == 'thead')
          table[0].find_index { |column| column.text.include? title }
        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in method #parent in FireFox 35.0. Try to use older version or use Chrome.